# Initialize an array of objects in Vue

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

I did use Objects in Arrays to read and it always worked but somehow it won't work for initialzing them. I need more variables inside articleList then only the number, so i can't just give the value to a normal array.

**This works:**

```
data(){
        return{
            articleList:[],
      }
}

in the method {
  number.forEach((e,i)=>{
                        this.articleList[i] = e
                    })
}
```

**This somehow won't work:**

```
 data(){
            return{
                articleList:[
                    {artNr:null}
                    ],
}
}
 in the method{
 number.forEach((e,i)=>{
                        this.articleList[i].artNr = e
                    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should to merge you current object with the `artNr` property as below:

```
this.articleList[i] = {...this.articleList[i], artNr: e}
```

or

```
Object.assign(this.articleList[i], { artNr: e })
```